# Creating year,month,date folder structure based on filename

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have some files in a some unix server. When i copy to windows, based on filename , the file has to be copied into corresponding year,corresponding month and corresponding date folders.                                                  Sample filename : 20120201.117_visual_sciences_web_feed.out.gz.
Folder structure to be created based on first part of filename, in this case : 20120201(YYYY,MM,DD) .                                                      In above example ,filename should be copied into 2012 -> 02-> 01 folder.Folders should be created if not created                                                      Honestly i am not getting how this can be implemented, please suggest.

Comment: What attempt have you made to address your question. Do you have any written script that can be worked on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for you -

```
@echo off

set filename=20120201.117_visual_sciences_web_feed.out.gz
set filepath=PATH\TO\%filename%

REM get the date from the file name
for /f "delims=." %%A in ("%filename%") do set fdate=%%A

REM Y=YEAR; M=MONTH; D=DAY
set Y=%fdate:~0,4%
set M=%fdate:~4,2%
set D=%fdate:~6,2%

REM echo %Y% %M% %D%

REM check to see if directories exist
if not exist \%Y% mkdir %Y%
if not exist \%Y%\%M% mkdir %Y%\%M%
if not exist \%Y%\%M%\%D% mkdir %Y%\%M%\%D%

REM copy the file to the newly created destination folder
copy %filepath% %Y%\%M%\%D%\%filename%

pause
```

I hope you're able to implement this into your script easily enough. As pointed out; if you added some examples from your script - I would be able to help more.

Comment: With few modifications it worked . Thanks a lot